# Notice: Undefined offset & Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I am trying to pull data from the json_decode array, I have done it before but this time I am getting extra issues.

This is what the json looks like.

```
{
"achievementpercentages": {
    "achievements": [
        {
            "name": "TF_SCOUT_LONG_DISTANCE_RUNNER",
            "percent": 54.668815612792969
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_HEAVY_DAMAGE_TAKEN",
            "percent": 47.104038238525391
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_GET_CONSECUTIVEKILLS_NODEATHS",
            "percent": 44.668777465820312
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_PYRO_CAMP_POSITION",
            "percent": 36.480117797851563
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_KILL_NEMESIS",
            "percent": 34.392494201660156
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_BURN_PLAYERSINMINIMUMTIME",
            "percent": 33.580135345458984
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_PYRO_BURN_MEDICPAIR",
            "percent": 32.748367309570312
        },
```

And my code is basically this

```
$achName = $decodedAch->achievementpercentages->achievements[$achCounter]->name;
$achPercent = $decodedAch->achievementpercentages->achievements[$achCounter]->percent;
```

The $achCounter is present in a while statement, in an effort to get all the achievements seperately.  I don't think that part is wrong, just how I am trying to access the data in the array.  I don't see what is wrong with it though.

Any help would be appreciated.

FULL WHILE STATEMENT AS REQUESTED

```
        while($achCounter < $responseCount)
    {
        $appid = $decodedSteam->response->games[$achCounter]->appid;
        $achievementURL = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid='.$appid.'&format=json';
        $jsonAch = file_get_contents($achievementURL);

        $decodedAch = json_decode($jsonAch);
        //var_dump($decodedAch);
        $achName = $decodedAch->achievementpercentages->achievements[$achCounter]->name;
        $achPercent = $decodedAch->achievementpercentages->achievements[$achCounter]->percent;
        //echo $achievementURL;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO steamid".$steamid."(name, percent) VALUES ('".$achName."','".$achPercent."')";
        $achCounter++;

    }
```

Comment: Show us your `while statement`, probably this part is wrong.

Comment: Okay, I added in the while statement.

Comment: `$achCounter` is your problem. You try to access an undefined index and then get a property from it.

Comment: An what is your `$responseCount`?

Comment: What about sql injection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate again after you fetch data from your url. Your $achCounter is usefull only for `$decodedSteam`, not for `$decodedAch`:

```
while($achCounter < $responseCount)
{
    $appid = $decodedSteam->response->games[$achCounter]->appid;
    $achievementURL = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid='.$appid.'&format=json';
    $jsonAch = file_get_contents($achievementURL);

    $decodedAch = json_decode($jsonAch);
    //var_dump($decodedAch);
    foreach($decodedAch->achievementpercentages->achievements as $achievement) { //HERE
        $achName = $achievement->name;
        $achPercent = $achievement->percent;
        //echo $achievementURL;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO steamid".$steamid."(name, percent) VALUES ('".$achName."','".$achPercent."')";
    }
    $achCounter++;
}
```